# Prove √2 exists by Archimedean Axiom

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I am trying to prove the existence of the square root of 2.

The proof: Let

$$S=\{x \in \mathbb{R} ∣x \ge 0, x^2 < 2\}.$$
I understand the proof of LUB, $\alpha$ and so I am at the step where $\alpha^2=2.$

I know that we are to prove by contradiction so we state let $\alpha^2 <2$ and $\alpha^2 >2$. Now my instructor wants us to use the Archimedean Axiom $1/n < \epsilon$.

$(\alpha^2 + 1/n)^2$ then what.....

Comment: This seems the same as [your other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1415235/prove-the-existence-of-the-square-root-of-2).